# How do you get the wider context HTML that wraps a given selector code in jQuery or Cheerio js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, cheerio

How do you get the entire HTML of h1 + ul > li > details > summary + p only if it has that structure? i.e. it wouldn't get the HTML of a ul tag element if it doesn't have a nested li, details etc.

```css
h1+ul>li>details>summary+p
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>T1</h1>
  <ul class="toggle">
    <li>
      <details>
        <summary><strong>Q1</strong></summary>
        <p>Answer1</p>
      </details>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1>T2</h1>
  <ul class="toggle">
    <li>
     <details>
       <summary>Q2</summary>
       <strong>Answer2</strong>
     </details>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the HTML that does NOT correspond to your expected selector but still gets selected - or do you want the WHOLE thing form the UL to have a specific style?

Comment: Sounds like you need a combined `.has` jQuery selector

Comment: So currently the CSS works on the `p` - you want the selector to select the UL and its descendants if they conform to your selector?

Comment: @mplungjan the question has been edited to include the second UL element that I don't want to select since it doesn't follow the ul>li>details>summary+p pattern. But in jQuery the pattern only returns the HTML to the last element i.e. p

Comment: @mplungjan exactly right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```js
const $collection = $("ul.toggle")
  .has("li>details>summary+p")
  .prev()
  .addBack()
  .addClass("red")
  
console.log($collection.text())
```

```css
.red { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>T1</h1>
  <ul class="toggle">
    <li>
      <details>
        <summary><strong>Q1</strong></summary>
        <p>Answer1</p>
      </details>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1>T2</h1>
  <ul class="toggle">
    <li>
     <details>
       <summary>Q2</summary>
       <strong>Answer2</strong>
     </details>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So this works but I realised, I have oversimplified my example. I've edited to include the h1 tags that I also want to select. This adds another layer of difficulty. $("h1 + ul.toggle").has("li>details>summary+p").addClass("red") wouldn't select the h1 since the first part just returns ul.toggle. I was thinking of maybe getting the previous sibling of ul after the first bit completes, but it seems hacky.

Comment: Also, I'm not too fussed about adding a class, I want to retrieve the raw HTML that conforms to the selector pattern

Comment: I updated the script since we can chain all the way